# SQL variable length numeric string

Tags: sql, dynamic, replace, sql-like

This query converts `bc_int_phone` to just numeric characters eliminating `-` and `''` characters. Say the numbers obtained need not have the same starting numeric. Say I'm searching for 123-456-7890 but this could be of the form 999 123-456-7890.. How do I incorporate the `like %(bc_phone_number)%` in this code to incorporate this case?

```
select 
    ca.callingpartynumber, ca.originalcalledpartynumber, ca.duration,
    ca.duration_text, ca.finalcalledpartynumber,  
    case 
       when calledpartylastname is not null 
         then ca.calledpartylastname + ',' + calledpartyfirstname 
         else p1.name 
    end as calledpartyname,
    p1.location, p1.dept, p1.title,
    case 
       when callingpartylastname is not null 
         then ca.callingpartylastname + ',' + callingpartyfirstname 
         else p3.name 
    end as callingpartyname
from 
    calldata.calldetailreport ca
join 
    ps_bc_peoplesource_base p1 on ca.originalcalledpartynumber like replace(p1.bc_int_phone, '-', '')
left outer join 
    ps_bc_peoplesource_base p3 on ca.callingpartynumber like replace(p3.bc_int_phone, '-', '')
where 
    callingpartynumber in (select replace(bc_int_phone, '-', '') internal_modified  
                           from ps_bc_peoplesource_base 
                           where bc_lan_id like 'f7c')
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Answer (score 0):

try `like ca.originalcalledpartynumber like '%'||replace(p1.bc_int_phone, '-', '')||'%'`

`||` is the concatenation operator for strings in oracle.
USe `+` if you are using SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!
really appreciate it!!